# Spring Restcontroller not returning xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I'm getting json response from my controller even though I added the xml annotations to my model. I get the list of users in json with no problems. Can I use @Entity and @XmlRootElement in the same class?

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usr")
@XmlRootElement
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, unique = true, length = 11)
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Post> post;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Friend> friends;

    public List<Friend> getFriends() {
        return friends;
    }

    public void setFriends(List<Friend> friends) {
        this.friends = friends;
    }

    public List<Post> getPost() {
        return post;
    }

    public void setPost(List<Post> post) {
        this.post = post;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }


    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }


    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }


    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }


    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

getAllUsers

```
 @Override
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionAnnotationFactory().openSession();
        Transaction trns = null;
        try {
            trns = session.beginTransaction();
            users = session.createQuery("select firstName, lastName, email, username as name from User").list();
            trns.commit();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            if (trns != null) {
                trns.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.flush();
            session.close();
        }
        return users;
    }
```

and in the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/api/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<User> getAllUsers() {

//List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
UserDao userdao = new UserDaoImpl();
List<User> users = userdao.getAllUsers();


return users;

 }
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you show your Spring configuration file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a nice [blog entry](https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc) from Spring about this. From there is this about content negotiation:

> **Enabling Content Negotiation in Spring MVC**
>
> Spring supports a couple of conventions for selecting the format
>   required: URL suffixes and/or a URL parameter. These work alongside
>   the use of Accept headers. As a result, the content-type can be
>   requested in any of three ways. By default they are checked in this
>   order:
>
> - Add a path extension (suffix) in the URL. So, if the incoming URL is
>     something like http://myserver/myapp/accounts/list.html then HTML is
>     required. For a spreadsheet the URL should be
>     http://myserver/myapp/accounts/list.xls. The suffix to media-type
>     mapping is automatically defined via the JavaBeans Activation
>     Framework or JAF (so activation.jar must be on the class path).
> - A URL parameter like this: http://myserver/myapp/accounts/list?format=xls.
>     The name of the parameter is format by default, but this may be
>     changed. Using a parameter is disabled by default, but when enabled,
>     it is checked second.
> - Finally the Accept HTTP header property is
>     checked. This is how HTTP is actually defined to work, but, as
>     previously mentioned, it can be problematic to use.

But if you just want to fix the return type I'd add the annotation `@RequestMapping(value="/api/users", produces={"application/xml"})` to your controller method.

Answer (score 0):

First, try to change

```
@RequestMapping(value="/api/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

to

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/api/users", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
```

Second, check out if client code ( I assume it is javascript ) is sending correct accept-type, because Jackson - the default serialization engine would derive format of response body from HTTP header.

Third, ensure that you have JAXB present in your classpath.

Comment: @ResponseBody even though i have RestController in the class specified? Nothing, still getting json, do I need the JAXB dependency?

Comment: What do you think your first suggestion will do?